# Laravel Relationship working, but showing it -> Trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, object-property

In my Controller I have:

```
public function showMainPage()
{
        $categories = Category::with('subcategories.products.prices', 'subcategories.products.image')->get();

        $data = array(
          "categories" => $categories,
        );

        return view('index')->with($data);
}
```

When I reference this in my view like this:

```
@foreach($subcategory->products as $product)
    <img src="{{ $product->image->thumbnail }}" alt="">
```

I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

This is my relationship:

**Product.php**

```
public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductImage');
    }
```

**This is my ProductImage Relationship:**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: Both relations have a `belongTo`, that's not right. Product should probably be `hasMany`.

Comment: @Scarwolf it seems like, in your view, you are getting an array instead of a collection. Could you please check using `$product['image']['thumbnail']`

Comment: Andrew: Ooh, you're right. Changed it to hasOne, still the same, though. (1 image row for each product). @jaysingkar That's working. Why do laravel returns an array though? How can I change that back to a collection...?

Comment: sorry @Scarwolf I'm not sure about that. However,you can try passing `$categories` directly without adding it to `$data` array.

Comment: Using `with` may be overriding your relationships. If you have relationships all the way down, try using just `Categories::all()`, then access everything through the relationships.

Comment: @jaysingkar have it like this now: `return view('index')->with('categories', $categories);` doesnt, work. Thank you though!

Comment: @aynber Changed it to `$categories = Category::all();`. Same error: `trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: How are you defining `$subcategory` in your view?

Comment: Have you tried dd($data) or print_r($data) ??

Comment: @aynbar By using a `foreach($categories->subcategories as $subcategory)` which works fine.

Comment: @KetavChotaliya Good catch! As you can see here in line 41: http://pastebin.com/U3FAtcsK image returns an array while prices returns a colletion how it should. But what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, You joined two table with relationship. When you fetch data from `categories` table it will return `categories` and `product` data.

As per given link by you: http://pastebin.com/U3FAtcsK, your `$data` variable contain this type of hierarchy.

```
category 
  subcategories
    products
      prices
      image
```

you are trying to display data of `image` array.

you have to fetch `image` data like this.

```
$categories->subcategories->product->image->thumbnail
```

Understand your Array Hierarchy. You didn't nothing wrong. :)